# How does a user-level thread come out of execution?

Tags: multithreading, scheduler

I understand that regarding the kernel-level threads, there is an interrupt caused by reaching a certain cycle count, that is signaling the kernel to perform the required context switch over to another thread depending on the scheduler.

In my understanding regarding user-level threads, in a many to one model the scheduling of the user threads is done completely in user space. The kernel just schedules the kernel thread user-level threads had been mapped to.

My problem is that I can't comprehend the bit after "the control has been transferred to a certain user-level thread". How does it cease to execute for the scheduler to get the control back to perform needed context switching and selecting of another thread for execution? I am not sure if there are any timer registers being used to cause an interrupt when it comes to user-level threads.

So once again how does the user-level scheduler get the control back?

Please enlighten me.

Comment: Your question seems to be off-topic here because, as I understand it, it is about how the os schedules threads and not diractly related to programming.

Comment: @Soana, I do not think it is offtopic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny thing (what a real coincidence) I've been formulating the answer to this in my head on my way home yesterday. For real.

The answer is that user-level thread has to give control back. Only kernel-level threads could be preempted. This control giving can happen either explicitly - by calling functions like `yield()` - or implicitly, by calling any other function which know how to transfer control. Those would be most likely thread-synchronization functions.